# data.table ifelse with multiple columns

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have a dataset with tens of columns that looks something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id= c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3), time=c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3),y1 = rnorm(9), y2= rnorm(9), x = rnorm(9), xb = rnorm(9))
df
#   id time      y1          y2           x          xb
# 1  1    1 -1.1184009 -1.07430118  0.61398523 -0.68343624
# 2  1    2  0.4347047 -0.53454071 -0.30716538 -1.02328242
# 3  1    3  0.2318315 -0.05854228  0.05169733 -0.22130149
# 4  2    1  1.2640080  2.07899296 -0.95918953 -0.35961156
# 5  2    2 -0.4374764 -0.25284854 -0.46251901  0.08630344
# 6  2    3  0.5042690  0.13322671  1.00881113  0.43807458
# 7  3    1  0.3672216  1.92995242  0.48708183  0.58206127
# 8  3    2 -1.5431709  0.53362731  1.17361087 -1.00932195
# 9  3    3 -1.4577268  0.23413541 -0.32399489 -0.91040641
```

I would like to modify my data frame using the following logic

```
df<-setDT(df)[,y1:=ifelse(y1>x,x,y1))]
df<-setDT(df)[,y2:=ifelse(y2>xb,xb,y2))]
```

However, since I have many variables I would like to do this in a single line expression. In other words, I would like to pass this function for multiple columns at once i.e. `y1` with `x`, `y2` with `xb` and so on...
I have tried the following but it does not seem to work

```
mod<-c("y1","y2")
max<-c("x","xb")
df2<-setDT(ppta)[,(mod):=ifelse(.(mod)>.(max),.(max),.(mod))]
```

does anyone knows what I am doing wrong? and how I modify multiple columns with their respective partner column at once?

Comment: What is it supposed to mean? For the comparison part, does it mean that any of mod columns is bigger than any of the max columns? Or is it supposed to be a comparison of all columns by all columns?

Comment: precisely I would like that every time that a column in `mod` has a higher value than its respective column in `max` the mod column changes its value to `max`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `pmin` instead of your `ifelse`. You can try:

```
mod<-c("y1","y2")
max<-c("x","xb")
setDT(df)    
df[,c(mod):=Map(pmin,mget(mod),mget(max))]
```

Explanation:

- `pmin` takes two (or more) vectors and gives the minimum value for each element (equivalent of your `ifelse(y1>x,x,y1)`);
- `mget` returns a list of objects from their names. For instance `mget("a","b")` returns a list with the `a` and `b` objects (if they exist). This is used to retrieve the column from their name in the environment of the data table;
- `Map` applies a function with more arguments element by element. `Map(f,a,b)` is equivalent to `list(f(a[[1]],b[[1]]),f(a[[2]],b[[2]]),...)`.

Comment: This seems to do the job, would you mind explaining a little more what is the logic of the function? I do not know the `Map` function